# Dinosaur game hack not working

Tags: javascript, console

I was making this hack for the google dinosaur game:

```
function speed(n) {
    Runner.instance_.setSpeed(n);
}

function noHit() {
    Runner.prototype.gameOver = function() {
        console.log("");
    }
}

function notNoHit() {
    Runner.prototype.gameOver = function() {
        this.playSound(this.soundFx.HIT);
        vibrate(200);

        this.stop();
        this.crashed = true;
        this.distanceMeter.acheivement = false;

        this.tRex.update(100, Trex.status.CRASHED);
    }
}
```

it is meant to be typed into the console, that way you don't have to edit the html of the page, which is pretty complicated (at least to me.) so, when i type it in, it returns *undefined*, as usual. when I use speed(*n*), it sets the speed to *n*. when i use noHit(), it makes it so i can't get hit. when i say notNoHit(), it returns *undefined*, as usual, but when i hit a cactus, it gives me an error:

```
Uncaught RefrenceError: vibrate is not defined
    at Runner.gameOver (<anonymous>:14:3)
    at Runner.update (data:text/html,chromewebdata:2005)
```

this kinda surprised me, because the way I did notNoHit() was to simply set the function back to what it was, instead of a junk command, (console.log("");) so i'm not really sure how to fix this.

Comment: No, you don't set it back to what it was, you set it to a new function that is created in the scope of `notNoHit` - which doesn't have access to `vibrate`.

Comment: so how would i fix this?

Comment: Store the original value in some variable before overwriting it, and then restore from there.

Answer (score 0):

Open the console of chrome browser write the below code it is working fine for me.

`Runner.instance_.gameOver=()=>{}`

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code by this Dinosaur will automatically jump when he will be near the obstacles

```
Runner.instance_.gameOver = function () { 
 this.playSound ( this.soundFx.HIT);
 vibrate(500);

 this.crashed = false;
 //this.tRex.endJump ();
 this.tRex.startJump (200);
// console.log  (this.tRex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Runner.prototype.gameOver=()=>{}`
Google has released a new version of the dino game.